# Get project-wide global variables from within a common module

Tags: python

I have a large project, which has grown to have its derivatives.
The main project and its derivatives are split into different repositories with a submodule called `common`.
The structure looks like this (oversimplified):

```
project1.git
    submodule "common"
    project1.py

project2.git
    submodule "common"
    project2.py

common.git
    functions.py
```

In some cases I need functions inside `common` to be aware of the project name and version, for instance to access a project-specific subfolder in `%APPDATA%`.

```
**project1.py**
PROJECT_NAME = "Project 1"
PROJECT_VERSION = "1.00"
from common import functions

**project2.py**
PROJECT_NAME = "Project 2"
PROJECT_VERSION = "1.01"

**common\functions.py**
from __main__ import PROJECT_NAME
import winreg

def getAppDataFolder():
    return os.path.join(winreg.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%"), PROJECT_NAME)
```

Of course I can pass around `PROJECT_NAME` variable in every function possible, but it is very verbose and inconvenient.

One of the ways to get rid of `from __main__ import PROJECT_NAME` is to use a `constants.py` file inside the `common` submodule, which will detect `PROJECT_NAME` from `sys.argv[0]`, but I don't like this solution, because I don't want the `common` submodule to have the names of all of my projects hardcoded inside of it.

I'm OK with a placeholder for `PROJECT_NAME`, but it needs to be declared once in the `**project1.py**` main script.

How do I import `PROJECT_NAME` correctly so it becomes a global variable for the submodule?

**Edit:** The person who closed the question clearly didn't understand it, because I wasn't asking about general importing of variables between files. This is much more specific - having variables with the same name in **different projects** using **common parts of code**, but the trick is to have the variables declared **outside of the common code**.

Comment: Note: the fact that you're using Git's submodules is not really relevant; you'd have exactly the same situation with Mercurial subrepos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up making a class called `Version` specifically for this purpose.
There is a `version.py` file in `common` subfolder.

```
class Version():

    PROJECT_NAME : str = "Project Name"
    PROJECT_VERSION : str = "0.00"
```

In **project1.py**:

```
from version import Version as v
v.PROJECT_NAME = "Project 1"
v.PROJECT_VERSION = "1.00"
```

In **project2.py**:

```
from version import Version as v
v.PROJECT_NAME = "Project 2"
v.PROJECT_VERSION = "1.01"
```

In **common\functions.py** and everywhere where it's necessary:

```
from version import Version as v

def function():
    print(v.PROJECT_NAME, v.PROJECT_VERSION)
```

The output of `function()` now depends on what project it is being run from.
The trick is not to create an instance of `Version` and just redefine its class variables in the main file of the project.

Answer (score -1):

I guess project 1 and project 2 are two independent programs or even a set of programs each. Then you could work like this:

1. Define a variable PROJECT_NAME in your "functions" module. E.g. set it no None. This is just to sattisfy the code checker and has no other meaning.
2. Right after the import statement of import functions add another line like this:

   import functions

   functions.PROJECT_NAME='project1'

This sets the variable in the module. In fact you wouldn't even have to define PROJECT_NAME in the submodule, but IDEs like Spyder will mark code using variable PROJECT_NAME suspicious otherwise.

Comment: That will not work, because the structure is not as simple as shown, there are plenty of different common classes, which are shared between multiple projects.
Therefore I'll need to set PROJECT_NAME for every particular file individually instead of having them import PROJECT_NAME themselves.